# Form validation (Event handling) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I've created a form in html and I've to validate it using JavaScript.First Name and Father's name shouldn't exceed 20 characters, so i've placed checks for them but they are working. Here's my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {
            var firstName=document.f1.firname.value;
            var fatherName=document.f1.fname.value;
            var address=document.f1.add.value;
            var phoneNumber=document.f1.ph.value;
            var cnic=document.f1.cnic.value;
            var email=document.f1.email.value;
            var cgpa=document.f1.fname.value;
            var sem=document.f1.sem.value;
            var id=document.f1.cid.value;
            if(firstName.length>20)
            {
                alert("Value can't exceed 20");
            }
            if(fatherName.length>20)
            {
                alert("Value can't exceed 20");
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="f1">
        Name : <input type="text",name="firname">  <br>
        Father's Name: <input type="text",name="fname"> <br>
        Address: <input type="text",name="add"> <br>
        Phone No.:<input type="text",name="ph"> <br>
        CNIC:<input type="text",name="cnic"> <br>
        Email:<input type="text",name="email"> <br>
        City :<br> <input type="radio" name="city" value="lhr"> Lahore <br>
        <input type="radio" name="city" value="karachi"> Karachi <br>
        <input type="radio" name="city" value="isl"> Islamabad <br>
        <select name="country">
            <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="india">India</option>
            <option value="china">China</option>
        </select> <br>
        Cgpa:<input type="text",name="cgpa"> <br>
        Department:<input type="text",name="dpt"> <br>
        <select name="degree">
            <option value="se">SE</option>
            <option value="cs">CS</option>
            <option value="it">IT</option>
        </select> <br>
        Semester:<input type="text",name="sem"> <br>
        CollegeId:<input type="text",name="cid"> <br>
        <input type="Submit", value="Submit" ,onsubmit="validate()">
    </form>
    </body>
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: There shouldn't be any commas separating attributes in HTML, this `<input type="Submit", value="Submit" ,onsubmit="validate()">` should be `<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="validate()">`

Comment: alert pop up still not appearing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use commas to separate HTML attributes. It should be:

```
Name : <input type="text" name="firname">  <br>
```

and not:

```
Name : <input type="text",name="firname">  <br>
```

The `onsubmit` event should be for the form, not the `input` button.

```
<form name="f1" onsubmit="validate()">
```